# Administrator can't demote or remove a site member who has been granted access to a folder and promoted him to Alfresco 'Site Manager'

Tags: alfresco, user-permissions

Hi guys am running Alfresco Community v4.2.0 (r54676-b4795). My challenge i **mistakenly granted a user Site manager rights** and i cant revoke them. Please help user may delete a site by mistake.

Comment: How are you trying to revoke them? What interface? What error do you get?

Comment: in documentlibrary i have created a folder called firms and then i went to the right far end and select manage permissions. this is where i managed to add the user  as site manager. Now i want to remove the permissions, under Actions column the edit or delete button is not showing in the column only for the site manager all the other levels e.g consumer, collaborator if i hover a mouse in the Actions column they buttons will appear.